# how can a ppt be shown on a website

Tags: html, embed, flash, powerpoint

Aim: To display an autoplaying power point presentation on my website.

I have a ppt and I want it to be played automatically on a section in home page of my website. I tried converting it to .swf and using embed tag tried to put it on web page, the slides were visible but it was not auto played. A mouse click on the section was need to move to next slide. Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <embed src="raahippt.swf"> 

   </body>
</html>
```

here is my output:

http://raahiholidays.in/sia/raahi.html

Comment: We need more information (What was the input file like? How was it converted?) before we can help you with this. If the conversion was done programmattically then you should [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here so that we can reproduce the issue. If the conversion *wasn't* done via code that you wrote, then your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your code suggests that you're trying to embed a Flash SWF.  I don't understand what this has to do with PowerPoint.  A google search for "embed swf in html" (without the quotes) will turn up lots of examples.  Here's a good one:  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp

Comment: I have converted ppt file into .swf file using online converters. and then inserted into HTML using embed tag.. I can view the content bt its not autoplaying.. a mouse click is required to move to next slide/content..  Basically my aim is to display an autoplaying power point presentation on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great and quick way is via **Google Drive**.

First upload your PowerPoint to your Google Drive account. Then on your google drive version of your powerpoint get the shareable URL and use that to replace the code below `<INSERT  URLhttp://XXXXXX.com/XXXXXX.ppt>`

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<INSERT  URLhttp://XXXXXX.com/XXXXXX.ppt>&embedded=true" style="width:600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```